# Enabling vertical scroll on HTML tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm creating a table and populating it using javascript. I want to add a vertical scroll bar to the table, but on the data only, i.e. I want the table header to remain fixed, i.e. not be included in the scroll.

I want to use only javascript, CSS and valid HTML5 elements. At this stage I want to exclude jQuery. There have been many discussions on this topic, usually including horizontal scroll bars. I'm only interested in vertical scrolling and to me it is essential that the header columns must be aligned with the table data when scrolled. The discussions and my attempts to achieve this, lead me to believe this is impossible. If this is not the case can someone tell me how this is done?

So far I have made a number of attempts. Adding

```
        table {
            display: block;
            height: 300px;
            overflow: scroll;
        }
```

causes vertical scrolling of the whole table, including the header and data, but the headers and data are aligned. Adding 
            thead {
                display: block;
            }
            tbody {
                display: block;
                height: 300px;
                overflow: scroll;
            }
results in the header not scrolling, but the headers and data columns are no longer aligned. What appears to be happening is that the width of the header columns no longer takes account of the data columns.

I've tried numerous other approaches without success. I've had partial success by adding the same width value to header and data field columns based on the maximum field size, in characters, of the header and data values. With this approach I can get the header to align with the data for most columns. However, I don't regard this as an adequate solution, as it is in general not possible, or at least very difficult, to determine a value in em, px or mm, that will hold n characters exactly.

In the discussions I've seen, it seems that what I want to achieve is possible using jQuery. I've not yet embraced jQuery, but if it can easily enable what I want, it may be the time to do so. Can anyone confirm if what I want is possible in jQuery?

I find it hard to believe that what I want to do is not easily possible, as I would regard it as essential for any adequate handling of tables.

Comment: Sadly this is **very** non-trivial. It shouldn't be, you'd think we could say "scroll the `tbody` element," but sadly no. You'll probably want to use any of several table plugins rather than writing your own.

Comment: Could you provide a sample HTML output in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the answer you're looking for, but a rather simple solution would be to put all the scrollable rows and columns within a scrollable div, and keep the headers and footers outside that div.

Comment: As requested I've set up an example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fJPEa/). This includes the suggestion proposed by Bradley Trager of using explicit column widths. I have already tried this and in my original screen set up these widths using javascript. However, I don't regard this as a workable solution: a) it is complicated and b) it is unstable as it is almost impossible to get the columns just the right size to hold the field and a small change like, changing the header font size, will break it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to set your columns at a fixed width, you can basically make two tables - one for the header and one for the body, and then just set scrolling on the body.

HTML:

```
<table class="header">
    <thead>
        <td>Header</td><td>Header</td><td>Header</td>
    </thead>
</table>
<table class="body">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And your css:

```
td, th{
    width:50px;
}
table.body{
     display: block;
     height: 300px;
     width:200px;
     overflow: scroll;
}
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bradleytrager/XyDse/).